# Check if window is minimized in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am developing a UWP application for Windows 10. I want to show a message dialog box when user reduces the size of the window. As of now, I have tried to implement the feature using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.sizechanged). My purpose is being fulfilled here except the message dialog appears when user either minimizes the window or changes its size. I have also attached the code snippet below. Thank you.

```
private async void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("");
            if (!appView.IsFullScreen)
            {
                if (!msgboxshown)
                {
                    messageDialog = new MessageDialog("To run the application smoothly, please maximize the window.");
                    msgboxshown = true;
                    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                    msgboxshown = false;
                }
            }
            args.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My purpose is being fulfilled here except the message dialog appears when user either minimizes the window or changes its size.

<s>When app minimizes, it will invoke `EnteredBackground` event, you could detect it and show your message dialog.</s>

```
 public App()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
     this.EnteredBackground += App_EnteredBackground;
 }

 private async void App_EnteredBackground(object sender, EnteredBackgroundEventArgs e)
 {
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("To run the application smoothly, please maximize the window.");

     await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
 }
```

**Update**

As  @Raymond Chen said, it looks os bug. So please use the above methods with caution.

Comment: I don't think you can show a `MessageDialog` from a background application. (Even if it could, the user won't be able to see it because the app is minimized.) You'll have to display a toast.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yep, but for my testing I could see the `MessageDialog`  on the screen  top left corner.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the OS.